# HTML Removing specific borders

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the borders of the last row so it just seems like a gap. Any suggestions? Thank you!

[image: IMAGE of the HTML Table]

Comment: Please provide us your html structure to give you some hints.

Comment: Please add the html to your post, instead of just an image of it. The CSS too, if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border of the last row's cells

```
tr:last-of-type td {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look like a gap, use [pseudo-selectors](https://w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
table tr:last-child td{
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nth element of a particular type using the nth-of-type pseudo-selector.

```
    <style>
        tr:nth-of-type(n){
            border: 0px;
        }
    
    </style>
```

Although it is not advisable to use a style tag in your HTML. You can always use a separate CSS file.

Alternatively, for the first and the last element, `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` can also be used.